# Retrieve old push notification from parse

Tags: ios, notifications, parse-platform

first of all pls sorry for my question, it may appear silly, but i'm in a very early stage of IOS and parse programming.
I manage to create my app in order to receive remote push notification from parse.
I would like to save in one array all push notifications sent from parse to the app.
If i well understood, i can achieve it only if the user tap on the notification, in that way user tap on iphone , "wake" it and so i can execute the code to save the push notification.
But in case user do not tap on it, the data is lost. Same if the push notification has an expiry time, and in that timeframe i have no internet connection.
Is there a way to retrieve, from app, all the sent notifications for the app ? like i was querying any table in dashboard/data browser ?

Many thanks in advance for your help

If my request is not clear, pls tell me

B. regards
Fabrizio

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Class on your Parse Database and when you create and send you push object, you also save it in background in the new table. 
So, when you need to retrieve any push notification atributes you should have them all stored in your database.

Comment: But this cannot be done by the dashboard, right ? in this case i need to create an app to send push .. or there is another way ? Tks for your reply